# How do I create a List of classes?

Tags: scala

I am trying to create a List of classes, like this:

```
abstract class Animal {
    def name = this.getClass.getName
    def say: String
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    def say = "Woof" 
}
class Cat extends Animal {
    def say = "Meow"
}
val animalClasses = List(Dog, Cat)
```

This falls over on the last line, with the error message:

```
Zoo.scala:18: error: not found: value Dog
```

Note that I could create a List of instances of classes easily with `List(new Dog(), new Cat())`, but that's not what I want.

Comment: As another answer suggested, you can do

    `val animalClasses = List(classOf[Dog], classOf[Cat])`

but are you sure you want to go down that road? Your use case can almost certainly be improved to a better design, one that uses type members and type parameters instead of using classes as values. How and for what do you intend to use this list?

Comment: My actual application is ofr a list of Strategies in [Pris.scala](https://github.com/cabalamat/prisdil/blob/master/Pris.scala). I created the Animals example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I didn't think you were actually doing something involving animals :) I mean, do you pass these values around? What kind of logic they are involved in? Can you use some enumeration-like structures instead of actual classes? Did you consider case classes? The only real use case I ever needed to use classOf in my two years of using Scala was when I needed to manually include the class name in every log entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go:

```
scala> List(classOf[Dog],classOf[Cat])
res1: List[Class[_ >: Cat with Dog <: Animal]] = List(class Dog, class Cat)
```

As per [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/109):

> The predefined function classOf[T] returns a runtime representation of the Scala class type T.

Comment: This works, but I can't make an instance of one of my classes, e.g. `val puss = new classOf[Cat]` fails.

Comment: I would say this is a different question, and you are looking at [Scala reflection](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html). That said, it might be overkill, and I would consider @slouc 's advice. Looking at your Pris file, you could `match/case` the class name of your object against the known classes' names  (they all already have a `name` variable, so you could just check against that). You will have to handle `DefAtEnd` differently because of the parameter at construct (something I think you couldn't catch with the runtime approach).